# Pivot In clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

I want to do a pivot in clickhouse 
I have data in the form of

```
rule_name | result
'string_1', 'result_1'
'string_2', 'result_2'
'string_3', 'result_3'
'string_4', 'result_4'
```

I want to pivot it to this such that string_1, string_2 ... are columns
and the resultant should have 4 columns and one row(result_1, result_2, result_3, result_4)

```
string_1 | string_2 | string_3 | string_4
result_1 | result_2 | result_3 | result_4

┌─string_1────┬─string_2─────┬─string_3─────┬─string_4─────┐
│ result_1      result_2        result_3      result_4
└─────────────┴──────────────┴──────────────┴──────────────┘
```

How do I achieve this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pivot or equivalent in clickhouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61781720/pivot-or-equivalent-in-clickhouse)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select anyIf(result, rule_name = 'string_1') string_1,  
       anyIf(result, rule_name = 'string_2') string_2,
       anyIf(result, rule_name = 'string_3') string_3,
       anyIf(result, rule_name = 'string_4') string_4
       from (
select 'string_1' rule_name, 'result_1' result
union  all select 'string_2', 'result_2'
union  all select 'string_3', 'result_3'
union  all select 'string_4', 'result_4')

┌─string_1─┬─string_2─┬─string_3─┬─string_4─┐
│ result_1 │ result_2 │ result_3 │ result_4 │
└──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

Comment: I want to pivot it to this such that string_1, string_2 ... are columns and the resultant should have 4 columns and one row

Comment: how to understand which row address which column?

Comment: Thanks, The second query is not giving the right result. I need this.

`┌─a────────────────┬─b────────────────┬─c────────────────┬─d────────────────┐
│ string_2
result_2 │ string_3
result_3 │ string_1
result_1 │ string_4
result_4 │
└──────────────────┴──────────────────┴──────────────────┴──────────────────┘

1 rows in set.`

Comment: I 've added one more example. Your question is really extra mega confusing.

Comment: Sorry, for the confusion. This is exactly what I needed.