# How to group mysql rows with same column value into one row in ClickHouse?

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I'm using this query in ClickHouse:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  iap.EventId,
  iap.Id as Title,
  ole.RewardId,
  ole.RewardGain,
  if((ole.RewardType = 'Currency' and ole.RewardId = 'Cash'), ole.RewardGain, null) as Soft
FROM OpenLootboxEvent ole 
ANY LEFT OUTER JOIN InAppPurchaseEvent iap
ON ole.EventSourceId = iap.EventId
WHERE iap.Id in ('superHotDeal');
```

This query return result:

```
EventId  Title         RewardId  Gain  
---------------------------------------------------------------------
111      superHotDeal  m3        5    
111      superHotDeal  m14       13         
111      superHotDeal  m20       25         
111      superHotDeal  Cash      282            
111      superHotDeal  Talent    null   
111      superHotDeal  Hard      null
```

Each "EventId" and "Title" has 6 meanings, where "RewardId" can have value from "m1" to "m26"  and it always can have "Cash", "Talent", "Hard" values.

How can I retrieve all the rows with the same "EventId" and "Title" in the same row?

Like this:

```
EventId  Title         man1  man1Cards   man2  man2Cards   man3  man3Cards  Cash  Talent  Hard                     
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
111      superHotDeal  m3  5             m14   13          m20   25         282   null    null
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select EventId, Title, groupArray(tuple(RewardId, RewardGain))
from (
SELECT DISTINCT
  iap.EventId EventId,
  iap.Id as Title,
  ole.RewardId RewardId,
  ole.RewardGain RewardGain,
  if((ole.RewardType = 'Currency' and ole.RewardId = 'Cash'), ole.RewardGain, null) as Soft
FROM OpenLootboxEvent ole 
ANY LEFT OUTER JOIN InAppPurchaseEvent iap
ON ole.EventSourceId = iap.EventId
WHERE iap.Id in ('superHotDeal'))
group by EventId, Title
```

[Pivot In clickhouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62306158/pivot-in-clickhouse)

Comment: Hi, thanks for help, but this query returns result like:
`| 111           |SuperHotDeal   | [('m3','5'),('m2','25'),('Cash','282'),('Talent','50')] |` 

But each value is required in a separate column like this:
Header:
`|EventId | Title | Man1 | Man1Card | Man2 | Man2Card | Man3 | Man3Card | Cash |Talent |Hard`.
As I showed in my question above

Comment: then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62306158/pivot-in-clickhouse

Comment: This option is also not suitable, because as a result of the request I do not have static data, as I wrote in my question.But the result of 1 EventId is always 6 values

Comment: SQL defines that a number of columns in the query result is known prior the query execution.

Comment: @N.Ayaz because it's unsolvable by your definition.